# UL Text Menu: Inline converted to Block via Media Query - Display Issues

Tags: css, menu, css-selectors, html-lists

I have text-menu code that works well.  It uses a standard UL and is set to only display the items INLINE with a divider BETWEEN the elements (only), and ONLY when those elements are on the same line.

See the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gbww05e/

HTML:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
<li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 3 - with expanded text that when below 471px should use ellipsis instead of wrapping</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List Item 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.topmenu {width: 100%; padding: 0; text-align: left;}
ul.topmenu li { display: inline;  }
ul.topmenu li:after {
content: " ";
word-spacing: 1.1em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 60%;
background-image:  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAOElEQVQI113M0Q3AIBRC0aM76P7jmHSmSj/6mibyc4EQkEEWuYtDmU1SXO1d6H7tjgupIl8+P+cD22cff9U1wbsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}

@media (max-width:470px) {
ul.topmenu {overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;}
ul.topmenu li {display:block; white-space: nowrap;}
ul.topmenu li:before {
content: " ";
word-spacing: 1.1em;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 60%;
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAOElEQVQI113M0Q3AIBRC0aM76P7jmHSmSj/6mibyc4EQkEEWuYtDmU1SXO1d6H7tjgupIl8+P+cD22cff9U1wbsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
}
```

The problem is, I am trying to add a media query so that when under 471px the menu is no longer inline but rather displays as a normal single-column list with left-bullets and using 'ellipsis' for any elements that are too long.  As you can see in the fiddle, the list converts fine to a single column going from inline to block, and retains single lines using nowrap - however I cannot seem to display the bullets at the beginning of the items, nor make the 'ellipsis' function work, no matter what I do.

I have looked at a number of postings here but I am having a hard time finding answers that relate to this technique or simply not looking up the right terms.

Notes:

(1) The bullets: You will note that if you add ANYTHING to the " " specified in the media query, the bullet appears fine (but with that text, unfortunately) - but if you leave it as just a space - nothing.  Since the space-only method works in the :after designation, I don't understand why it fails in the :before.

(2) The ellipsis:  If in the media query you leave the items as 'inline', you will see that the ellipsis works as expected when under 471px - although the items are no longer in a single column.  As soon as switching to block - it is a no go.  Again, I have tried various options but just not able to get it to work.

Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What about, changing in the max-width: 470px media query:

```
ul.topmenu li {display:block; white-space: nowrap;}
```

with:

```
ul.topmenu li {display:list-item; white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but seems to have no effect - note the fiddle I have for this question and if you have any further thoughts they would be greatly appreciated... http://jsfiddle.net/4gbww05e/